# My if statement conditions are not triggering properly despite the conditions being met

Tags: python

I'm learning how to program with Python by taking up small projects to get myself familiarized. I'm stuck on a tiny problem in which my if statement is not being triggered properly despite the conditions being met during the programs execution. this is the dice simulation project I made on my own.

I could not think of any additional methods at this time since I'm still a novice but learning as i'm going

```
import random
import time

print("Welcome to the dice simulator, lets find out how lucky you are!")

"\n"

min = 1
max = 6

roll = input("Do you want to play? ")

while roll == "yes" or roll == "y" or roll == "Yes" or roll == "Y":

    print("Now rolling both dice....")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("calculating....")
    time.sleep(3)

    print(random.randint(min, max))
    print(random.randint(min, max))

    if min == max: #This if condition does not work even if the dice match. Needs work.
        print("Amazing! You scored a double!")
    else: #This else condition works regardless of the outcome.
        print("Oof! Might wanna keep trying!")

    roll_again = input("Roll again? y/n: ")
    if roll_again == "n" or roll_again == "no" or roll_again == "No" or roll_again == "N":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    # else:
    #     print("Invalid answer")
    #     break
```

If the if condition is met, a message will print congratulating the user for scoring a double number such as 1,1 or 6,6 for example. If the dice does not show matching number's, the else condition will print a message telling the user to better luck next time.

Comment: `min` is always 1 and `max` is always 6, so that if statement is never true, even when the random numbers are the same.

Comment: `min` and `max` are built-in functions. They are not a good choice for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you preset **min** and **max** which will never be changed. Therefore, **if min == max** cannot be True.

You can simply keep the results in new variables:

```
dice_1 = random.randrange(1, 7)
dice_2 = random.randrange(1, 7)
```

Then compare dice_1 and dice_2 for your conditions

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a better way to fix this now!

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:-**

```
import os
import datetime

directory = r'C:\Users\vasudeos\OneDrive\Desktop\Test Folder'
extensions = (['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']);
import random
import time

print("Welcome to the dice simulator, lets find out how lucky you are!")

"\n"

min = 1
max = 6

roll = input("Do you want to play? ")

while roll == "yes" or roll == "y" or roll == "Yes" or roll == "Y":

    print("Now rolling both dice....")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("calculating....")
    time.sleep(3)

    min1 = random.randint(min, max)
    max1 = random.randint(min, max)

    print("{}\n{}".format(min1, max1))


    if min1 == max1: #This if condition does not work even if the dice match. Needs work.
        print("Amazing! You scored a double!")
    else: #This else condition works regardless of the outcome.
        print("Oof! Might wanna keep trying!")

    roll_again = input("Roll again? y/n: ")
    if roll_again == "n" or roll_again == "no" or roll_again == "No" or roll_again == "N":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
```

As others have pointed, variables `min` and `max` have constant values (1, 6) throughout the execution of the program, and since their values aren't the same, and don't even change `if min == max` will always be false.